# Pattern decorator with template class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to create a generic class for decorator pattern.

I successfully did it with the example code by metaprogramming:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Action1 { };
struct Action2 { };

class Classe
{
public:
  // Default template.
  template<class U, class ...Args>
  auto go(Args ...args)
  {
    //static_assert(false);
  }
};

// Action 1.
template<>
auto Classe::go<Action1>()
{
  std::cout << "coucouGo1" << std::endl;
}

// Action 2.
template<>
auto Classe::go<Action2>(int i)
{
  std::cout << "coucouGo2 : " << i << std::endl;
  return i;
}

template <class T>
class Decorator
{
public:
  template<class U, class... Args>
  auto go(Args ...args)
  {
    std::cout << "coucouDecorator" << std::endl;
    return classe.template go<U>(args...);
  }
private:
  T classe;
};

class DecoreClasse : public Decorator<Classe>
{
};

int main()
{
  DecoreClasse c;
  c.go<Action1>();
  c.go<Action2>(2);
}
```

There is different functions "Action" and the pattern template decorator add a "coucouDecorator" before all call.

But the thing I don't like is the "auto" return type.

How can I replace `auto` to `int` or `char` in template specialization. I know I can do

```
struct Action1 { typedef retval int };
struct Action2 { typedef retval char };

template<>
Action1::retval Classe::go<Action1>()
```

and add a class template to the decorator

```
  template<class U, class T, class... Args>
  T go(Args ...args)
  {
```

but I prefer not to add return type in the struct.

Do you have a better idea ? Sometimes I'm not very understandable in English so do not hesitate to ask question.

Comment: This code looks very hypothetical. Can yyou give a real life working example please?

Comment: The "main" example are here. In the Classe, I implement lots of functions go<Action*> and I would like to benchmark the time between the start and the return time.

Comment: And what's so wrong about `auto`?

Comment: I would like to say "return 1" instead of "return static_cast<char>(1)". This is like a POC: a very basic example to be implemented in a real situation.

Comment: I think you are stuck with the `auto` and being explicit about the return value. Any other approach will involve more boiler plate in each specialization or wrapping each specialization in a class.